# python regex to find any link that contains the text 'abc123'

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifuly soup to find all href tags.

```
links = myhtml.findAll('a', href=re.compile('????'))
```

I need to find all links that have 'abc123' in the href text.

I need help with the regex , see ??? in my code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `'abc123'` is *literally* what you want to search for, anywhere in the `href`, then `re.compile('abc123')` as suggested by other answers is correct.  If the actual string you want to match contains punctuation, e.g. `'abc123.com'`, then use instead

```
re.compile(re.escape('abc123.com'))
```

The `re.escape` part will "escape" any punctuation so that it's taken literally, just like alphanumerics are; without it, some punctuation gets interpreted in various ways by RE's engine, for example the dot (`'.'`) in the above example would be taken as "any single character whatsoever", so `re.compile('abc123.com')` would match, e.g. `'abc123zcom'` (and many other strings of a similar nature).

Answer (score 1):

`"abc123"` should give you what you want

if that doesn't work, than BS is probably using `re.match` in which case you would want `".*abc123.*"`

Comment: but it is any href that contains 'abc123' anywhere in the href url.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the links with exactly 'abc123' you can simply put:

```
links = myhtml.findAll('a', href=re.compile('abc123'))
```